# How can I write a zipped shapefile with ogr2ogr and /vsizip/?

Tags: shapefile, gdal, ogr, ogr2ogr

After reading a bit of [GDAL Virtual File Systems docs](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_virtual_file_systems.html), I am trying to write a zipped Shapefile using this gdal command involving the use of `/vsizip/`:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" /vsizip/test.zip\test.shp WFS:"https://www.wondermap.it/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?&map=/home/ubuntu/qgis/projects/Demo_sci_WMS/demo_sci.qgs&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&typename=domini_sciabili&bbox=544138,5098446,564138,5108446"
```

, and I get this error:

```
ERROR 1: Read-write random access not supported for /vsizip
ERROR 1: Cannot create test.shx while another file is being written in the .zip
ERROR 1: Failed to create file /vsizip/test.zip/test.shx: No such file or directory
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation of layer domini_sciabili (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
```

The code is only writing `test.shp` (0KB though) inside `test.zip`.

I get what is happening (the error is self-explanatory), but sincerely, I don't know if I can go farther than this without probably using the GDAL API. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself thanks [to this answer](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Piping-ogr2ogr-SHP-format-vsistdout-to-unix-command-tp5389350p5389353.html) on the GDAL mailing list.

I can't, because Shapefile is a multi file format, and OGR updates
the files in a non sequential way. I have to create a temporary shapefile
and zip it afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

In GDAL 3.1+ you can create zipped shapefiles, although not using `vsizip` (as far as I've tested). See [docs page](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html#compressed-files)

> Starting with GDAL 3.1, the driver can also support reading, creating
>   and editing .shz files (ZIP files containing the .shp, .shx, .dbf and
>   other side-car files of a single layer) and .shp.zip files (ZIP files
>   contains one or several layers). Creation and editing involves the
>   creation of temporary files.

You simply need to change the output filename extension:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" C:\Temp\test.shp.zip WFS:"https://www.wondermap.it/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?&map=/home/ubuntu/qgis/projects/Demo_sci_WMS/demo_sci.qgs&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&typename=domini_sciabili&bbox=544138,5098446,564138,5108446"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the `.shp.zip` or the `.shz` extension to create a compressed shapefile. Example using the `.shz` extension:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -skipfailures /tmp/output.shz "https://irig-madeira.pt/postgresql/drote/public/baram_2020/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=ponto_cotado&EXCEPTIONS=application/json&srsname=EPSG:5016"
```

The contents can be checked with:

```
unzip -v /tmp/output.shz
Archive:  /tmp/output.shz
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
     156  Defl:N       68  56% 2023-05-30 23:25 93672253  output.shp
     708  Defl:N      184  74% 2023-05-30 23:25 06613a49  output.dbf
     116  Defl:N       61  47% 2023-05-30 23:25 e4d276c6  output.shx
--------          -------  ---                            -------
     980              313  68%                            3 files
```

Source: [GDAL documentation](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html#compressed-files)